# How to start over after the last row in datasource in iMacros

Tags: loops, datasource, imacros

I have over 10 accounts on a website and on that website i want to log in with account 1, do some actions, logout and then login to account 2 etc etc.
After i've logged in in the last account, i want my Macro to start over at account 1, so row 1 in my datasource.

What i'm doing now is the following:

```
    SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.exampe.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:email CONTENT=email1
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=pass1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LOGIN
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/action1.php
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:fjkd ATTR=ID:1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:fjkd ATTR=*
WAIT SECONDS=1
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/action2.php
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=NAME:f ATTR=ID:2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=*
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/logout.php

URL GOTO=http://www.exampe.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:email CONTENT=email2
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=pass2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LOGIN
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/action1.php
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:fjkd ATTR=ID:1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:fjkd ATTR=*
WAIT SECONDS=1
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/action2.php
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=NAME:f ATTR=ID:2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=*
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/logout.php
```

And so on, so the script is very long, but it can loop all the time.

What i would like is to load the login credentials from my datasource and replay them as long as i want, it would be much easier to add or delete an account. Or to change the actions on the website for all the accounts.

I hope this is possible!

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hopes are realistic. Let's suppose that your datasource file (*'credentials.csv'*) looks like:

```
email1,pass1
email2,pass2
email3,pass3
...
```

You can loop "infinitely" over the accounts by means of the macro below. Just play it in loop mode with a very big 'Max:' value (e.g. 99999).

```
' rows in the datasource '
SET maxRow 10

SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE credentials.csv
SET curRow EVAL(({{!LOOP}}%{{maxRow}}==0)?{{maxRow}}:{{!LOOP}}%{{maxRow}};)
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{curRow}}
SET email {{!COL1}}
SET pass {{!COL2}}

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.exampe.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:email CONTENT={{email}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT={{pass}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LOGIN
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/action1.php
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:fjkd ATTR=ID:1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:fjkd ATTR=*
WAIT SECONDS=1
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/action2.php
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=NAME:f ATTR=ID:2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=*
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/logout.php
```